# JBOSS: Invalid algorithm http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315 (InclusiveC14N)

Tags: java, web-services, security, jboss, cxf

I am using JBOSS EAP 6.3.1 - I am not allowed to use wildfly in production.

CXF Version 2.7.11

I am trying to build a secure token service, which can handle a RequestSecurityToken request, while using a X509 certificate for authentication.

*Example Request from a third party application - sadly can not be changed:*

```xml
<SOAPENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAPENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
 <SOAPENV:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
   <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary' ValueType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3' wsu:Id='Token'>
MIIDMTCCApqgAwI....3aairt
93OqNtk=
</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
   <Signature xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#'>
    <SignedInfo>
     <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'/>
     <SignatureMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1'/>
     <Reference URI='#body'>
      <Transforms>
       <Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1'/>
      <DigestValue>WbLbIc...k=</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
     <Reference URI='#Timestamp'>
      <Transforms>
       <Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1'/>
      <DigestValue>z3q....9w=</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
     <Reference URI='#Token'>
      <Transforms>
       <Transform Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature'/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm='http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1'/>
      <DigestValue>ypE6U....slo=</DigestValue>
     </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>lW1....Tc=</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
     <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      <wsse:Reference URI='#Token' ValueType='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3'/>
     </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
   <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id='Timestamp'>
    <wsu:Created>2015-03-25T13:03:11Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2015-03-25T13:13:13Z</wsu:Expires>
   </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
 </SOAPENV:Header>
 <SOAPENV:Body wsu:Id='body' xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd'>
  <wst:RequestSecurityToken xmlns:wst='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust'>
   <wst:TokenType>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc/sct</wst:TokenType>
   <wst:RequestType>http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/Issue</wst:RequestType>
  </wst:RequestSecurityToken>
 </SOAPENV:Body>
</SOAPENV:Envelope>
```

*These are my policy settings:*

```xml
   <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="CertificateSecurityPolicy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:AsymmetricBinding>
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:RecipientToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:RecipientToken>
                    <sp:InitiatorToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                                <wsp:Policy>
                                    <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                                    <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                                </wsp:Policy>
                            </sp:X509Token>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:InitiatorToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                            <sp:InclusiveC14N/>
                            <!--<sp:InclusiveC14N11/>-->
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Lax/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                    <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AsymmetricBinding>
             <sp:SignedParts>
                <sp:Body/>
                <sp:Header Namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"/>
           </sp:SignedParts>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Every request throws the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An error was
>   discovered processing the  header (**A bad
>   canonicalization algorithm was specified**)   at
>   org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.checkBSPCompliance(SignatureProcessor.java:721)
>   [wss4j-1.6.15.redhat-1.jar:1.6.15.redhat-1]   at
>   org.apache.ws.security.processor.SignatureProcessor.verifyXMLSignature(SignatureProcessor.java:405)
>   [wss4j-1.6.15.redhat-1.jar:1.6.15.redhat-1]

This is a followup question to:
[How to use CXF STS and X509v3 BinarySecurityToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670807/how-to-use-cxf-sts-and-x509v3-binarysecuritytoken)

**EDIT 1**

I need to set the property *ws-security.is-bsp-complian*t to false. Then I get a another error message:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.AlgorithmSuiteValidator.checkC14nAlgorithm(AlgorithmSuiteValidator.java:77) [wss4j-1.6.15.redhat-1.jar:1.6.15.redhat-1]
    at org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.AlgorithmSuiteValidator.checkSignatureAlgorithms(AlgorithmSuiteValidator.java:95) [wss4j-1.6.15.redhat-1.jar:1.6.15.redhat-1]
```

Apparently the following condition fails:

```
"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" == "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"
```

"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" Being extracted from the message. 
Now if I just could add REC-xml-c14n-20010315 to the allowed algorithm list...

**EDIT 2**

After reading the specification once again, I believe that cxf is ignoring the Element `sp:InclusiveC14N`. Do I need to place it somewhere else inside my wsdl

**EDIT 3**

The Class org.apache.cxf.sts.SignatureProperties defines the default algorithm as http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#

```java
public class SignatureProperties {
...
private String c14nAlgorithm = WSConstants.C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS;

private List<String> acceptedC14nAlgorithms = new ArrayList<String>();

public SignatureProperties() {
    ...
    // Default c14n algorithms
    acceptedC14nAlgorithms.add(c14nAlgorithm);
}
```

If I could only override this, it should work. How can it be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the InclusiveC14N policy was not supported in CXF/WSS4J until now. I've fixed this for the next release (3.0.5/3.1.0): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6333

Colm.